# [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/lib/libmyodbc.so' : file not found but file exist

Tags: c++, linux

I use ubuntu 15.10 64bit. I try to run a game server.
I alredy install libmyodbc it locate in use/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/
I have use ln s command to create shot link in use/lib but when i start server that message appear. I have changed driver url to use/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/ but no effect
Here is my odbc file in etc/odbc.ini

```
[ODBC Data Sources] 
odbcname = MyODBC 3.51 Driver DSN

[tlbbdb] 
Driver      = /usr/lib/libmyodbc.so
Description = MyODBC 3.51 Driver 
DSN SERVER       = 127.0.0.1
PORT        =3306 
USER        = root 
Password     = 123123
Database     = tlbb
OPTION      = 3
SOCKET       =
```

Comment: In Linux, 32bit libraries are usually located in `/usr/lib` while 64bit libraries in `/usr/lib64`. Is your game server 64bit? If it is looking for driver in `/usr/lib` chances are, it's a 32bit server.

Comment: Dear @alvits I don't know exactly how many bit of this sever it may 32bit in my usr folder do not have lib46 what should i do now.

Comment: You can use the `file` utility to find the bitness of your game server. For example if your gameserver is in `/usr/local/game/bin/server` you can then run `file /usr/local/game/bin/server` and it will tell you what file it is. If it turns out to be 32bit, you will need to get the 32bit odbc driver.

Comment: I just install 32bit package and change odbc file 
Driver = /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc.so then i run my server but i get same result 
I try to test connect by command 
sudo isql -v tlbbdb root 123123
and the result here 
Can't open lib '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc.so' : file not found
I very confuse.

Answer (score 0):

I have meet the same question, and i see a solution somewhere:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:<your-lib-path>
```

I tried, and it works. I hope that will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You may see this error due to a missing dependency. In my case, installing odbcinst resolved the issue:

```
sudo apt-get install odbcinst
```

Answer (score 0):

On Fedora, the following fixed it for me:

```
sudo dnf install mysql-connector-odbc
```